# Characterizing "typical behavior" for events?

Tags: time-series, outliers, pattern-recognition

I need to build a model to characterize what is typical for a series of events, which in turn will be used to flag atypical events. As an example, think of credit card purchases (how often? what amounts?) or weather events (how often? how intense?). Although eventually there will be more variable, for now we can stick to these two. An event therefore has a **time** and a **magnitude**.

Are there modelling techniques suitable for the above? If they happen to be implemented in an R package, I could use R to validate if they work, prior to implementing it in code.

In other words, the ultimate goal is anomaly (outlier) detection.

Thank you.

Comment: 1/2 As far as I know, outliers are determined by magnitude only. The benchmarks for outlier detection vary depending on what kind of data you have and the subject matter. (Ultimately, everything is relative). Most people would consider outliers to be any values that lie outside the top quartile and the bottom quartile. In regression analysis, a common metric for detecting influential observations is Cook's Distance and other leverage scores detailed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_%28statistics%29.

Comment: 2/2 As written, I think your question is too vague and may depend on subject-matter specific information. Also, it's not clear what your goals are. Are you looking for just outlier detection or also interested in predicting at what particular point in time an outlier will occur?

Comment: Thanks @rocinante. For 1st question: to simplify things, I can characterizing magnitude and time of occurrence separately. For magnitude, an outlier would be one > twice the current maximum.

Comment: For 2nd question: the goal is to detect "unusual" events. With the purchase analogy, this would mean purchases of values larger than in the past or more frequent.